# Debug With Mixed vs Debug with Native Only when debugging dump files

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, crash-dumps

When I open a dump file, in VS2012, I see two options for debugging: *Debug with Mixed* and *Debug with Native Only*. I am wondering what these two options mean, and what the differences are between them.

I tried searching Google for documentation/etc. but could not find anything on these two options, and the closest that I came was finding a few posts where people said they used *Debug with Mixed* but didn't say why, and one post that noted that *Debug with Native Only* displays only for .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether you choose Debug with Native Only or Debug with Mixed or Debug Managed Memory, depends on what your dump file is of.

1. **Debug with Native Only:** For native apps (it will allow you to see the callstack and source code from the native part of the app),
2. **Debug with Mixed:** Allows you to see the managed source code part as well.
3. **Debug Managed Memory:** Useful for debugging memory problems in managed code

Some links that might prove useful:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugger/archive/2009/12/30/what-is-a-dump-and-how-do-i-create-one.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5zhxt22.aspx#BKMK_Open_a_dump_file
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/10/16/net-memory-analysis-enhancements-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/05/understanding-symbol-files-and-visual-studio-s-symbol-settings.aspx

Comment: No problem! If you find any issues - report them using the Send-a-Smile feature (it's also in 2013) - we *DO* look at them http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=31113